# Discord.py Ban Command Issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Im having an issue with my ban command, my admins can ban each otherr and i dont want that,but im not sure how to fix it here my code

```
#Ban command
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} has been banned!')
```

I want it to make it like this but im pretty new to python and idk how to write it (the commented section)

```
#Ban command
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
  #if mentioned user has the same role as the author: 
    await ctx.send('Cant ban Moderators/Admins')
  else:
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} has been banned!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Ban command
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    check = False
    for i in member.roles:
        if i in ctx.author.roles[1:]:
            check = True

    if(check):
        await ctx.send('Cant ban Moderators/Admins')
    else:
        await member.ban(reason=reason)
        await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} has been banned!')
```

Comment: How would i make that global though? Like if my bot is in many different servers. I want it where if the person has the same role they cant ban each other, nor anyone with a higher role. But i want ppl with a higher role to be able to ban the lower roles.

Comment: @ParrotSec03 There is no hierarchy in Discord roles as far as I know, since they're not default but made by the server owner. I updated my post so that if the moderator tries to ban someone with the moderator's role it fails.

This does however result in that it fails if they share ANY role. This is the best I could find with my limited knowledge of this library so maybe someone else has a better solution.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help, this will work untill i get to learn more about python. Thanks!